# Will I need to enable expand-rootfs if I use NOOBS?

Tags: raspbian

I am going to install Raspbian with NOOBS. I have read several places that it is good to expand the root file system. Do I need to do this if I install Raspbian with NOOBS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install raspbian with NOOBS you can try to expand it, but the command in raspi-config will say, that it is already expandend because you probably used Noobs.

So the answer is: No, you don't have to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You will still need to expand the file system.  It can be done under the config menu accessed by

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and selecting the corresponding option.  It's pretty painless.